# Is there a way in Symfony 6 maker bundle to make add_date default value like CURRENT_TIMESTPAM in cmd? Or should edit every time i create datetime?

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, types

Here is example of not availabe adding data for :
[image]

Comment: Please never present textual details as screenshots on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Unfortunately not currently, the only way is to manually add it in the entity class. I agree, this should be added. It was [asked here](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/641) a few years ago with no plans to add it. I might make a PR..

Comment: to any person who cannot see your image your total question is "*| Here is example of not availabe adding data for |* instead just **use copy/paste** (then details like AgreeableElephant seen by all)